# Lookup in other tab of excel sheet

Tags: excel

I have excel sheet having two tabs in it, A and B

```
In A excel tab the columns are ID, Price/Unit
In B excel tab the coulmns are ID, NumberOfSoldUnits
```

I want to get NumberOfSoldUnits in Column C in tab A excel on the basis of matching ID. How can achieve this using VLOOKUP ?

```
I have tried this : =VLOOKUP(A,B!A:B,2,0)
```

But giving error 508

Comment: Google search `VLOOKUP`. You will find tons of answer.

Comment: @harun24hr, I have tried one Vlookup but its showing error...Question updated..

Comment: @Joy You're just missing the row number in your first argument: `=VLOOKUP(A1,B!A:B,2,0)`